# Side by Side Image & Text: how to vertically center the text

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <h4>My Guide</h4>

  <div class="inner four-columns">
        <img src="{{ 'guide3.jpg' | asset_url }}" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>

    <div class=" inner four columns">
        <p>Content.</p>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Is there a simple way to vertically align the Text content without using tables?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be tables, but something similar that's more flexible, especially if you also want to make it responsible later:

The HTML wrapped by a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
        <img src="{{ 'guide3.jpg' | asset_url }}" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class=" inner">
      <p>Content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS applied to it:

```
.container {
  display: table;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertival-align: middle;
}
```

For smaller screens, you can set all these to `display: block;` in a media query (if you *want* to).

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of all children divs inside the `.container` to block, like this:

```
.outer > .inner { display: block; }
```